# Inferring the baseline height and bounding box widths of characters/text/equations in the 'standalone' environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, standalone, coordinates, dvi, baseline

I am writing a mathematics visualisation tool using C++ and OpenGL, and want to incorporate LaTeX text and equations. I was initially looking for a C++ library to directly render LaTeX text/equations as bitmaps and then rendered as textures onto the screen. But I figured that it would be simpler for me to to compile the required LaTeX code from C++, use dvipng to convert to a .png image, and then read the .png file as a texture, which can then be used by OpenGL. The one hurdle I am currently trying to resolve is how to infer the baseline of each line of text/math and the dimensions of the boxes of each character (for simplicity, let's assume that I only want to render single lines). Just in case I am incorrectly using the term 'baseline', I have indicated what I mean by 'baseline' in red in the images below. Each is a single line that was compiled as a separate document using the 'standalone' class, e.g:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\begin{document}
bake
\end{document}
```

[image: bake]

[image: page]

[image: eqn]

In the case of 'bake', the baseline coincides with the bottom of the document. In the case of 'page', the baseline is about 30% of the height of the document relative to the bottom. Likewise for the equation. For my use case, I would ideally like to split each string into individual characters in bounding boxes, so that I have fine-grain control over the layout and animation of each character. But in order to do so, I need to vertically align each word/character with respect to the others and also know the widths of the boxes bounding each word/character to allow for appropriate horizontal alignment. Can anyone advise me on how I can infer the relative height of the baseline for an arbitrary string of characters as well as the dimensions of the bounding boxes associated to each character?

Comment: The information you want should be available in the DVI file if you use a traditional TeX engine, combined with metrics from the appropriate TFM files—see [DVI format on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_independent_file_format). On the other hand, if you want to invest in more modern things like OpenType and `unicode-math`, [LuaTeX](http://luatex.org/) resources would be seem more relevant (see their mailing-lists in the “support” link?). I can't be more specific, sorry.

Comment: @frougon Thank you for these tips. I will read more about the above :)

Comment: Exercise 11.5 in The TeXbook deals with a similar question. It can perhaps be adapted to output box _dimensions_ rather than the boxes themselves.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thank you for pointing that out! I will have a look :)